# Accessing values inside a returned array

Tags: web3js, truffle

I am working with truffle and failing to get the actual values from my return:

```
[ [ { [String: '10'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '35'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '40'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '50'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '60'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] } ],
  [ { [String: '20'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '35'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '40'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '50'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] },
    { [String: '60'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] } ] ]
```

I tried `result.valueOf()[0][0].toString()` but that didn't do the trick.

However, `result.valueOf()[0].toString()` is working on the following example:

```
[ [ { [String: '10'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] } ],
  [ { [String: '20'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [Object] } ] ]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The goal is to use the values for a test, ideally somehow like that:

```
 assert.equal(result.valueOf()[0][0].toString(), [10, 35, 40, 50, 60]);
 assert.equal(result.valueOf()[1][0].toString(), [20, 35, 40, 50, 60]);
```

EDIT2: The values that the contract returns are `(uint256[], uint256[])`

Cheers!
carbee

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you also post how the response is being returned in the contract?

Comment: Yep, updated it in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just expecting an array return, try `console.log`ging: `result.args.c`, `result.args.c[0]`

The actual response usually ends up in `c`.

---

Update #1

If you were getting a return of arrays, then your overall response should be something like (with BigNumber instead of String):

```
[ [ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [Array] },
    BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [Array] } ],
  [ BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [Array] },
    BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [Array] } ] ]
```

From that, you have to map the array in order to make the array desired:

```
let arr = result.map(res => {
  return res.map(res => res.c[0])
})
```

You should get the array you want with `arr`.

Since `c` in your case is an `[Object]`, you'd have to see what is in that object and replace `res.c[0]` with the map to that object value you want. I assume its `.value`...but I don't have code to verify that right now. Hopefully this helps.

And just for reference `result.valueOf()[0][0].toString()` would actually be `result.valueOf()[0].c[0].toString()`.

Comment: I'd like to get two arrays: [10,35,40,50,60] and [20,35,40,50,60] or all values independently. I'll update my question!

Comment: @carbee Updated.